# How to perform such operations using Java API Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to consecutively perform the following operations on a stream.

1). I want to create a stream of numbers from `2` to `n`.

I guess this can be done like this: `IntStream.range(2, n)`.

2). Add filter, which let's the number to go further only if this number is not divisible by any other number that went through this filter already.

I'm having trouble to implement such filter. I think I have to create an anonymous class that will contain an `ArrayList` and I will store all the numbers that passed through this filter in this `ArrayList`. It all should look something like:

```
IntStream.range(2, n).filter(new IntPredicate() {
        ArrayList<Integer> prev;

        @Override
        public boolean test(int value) {
            if (prev == null) {
                prev = new ArrayList();
                return true;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < prev.size(); i++) {
                if (value % prev.get(i) == 0) {
                     return false;
                }
            }
            prev.add(value);
            return true;
        }
```

3). Get `Map<Integer, Integer>`, where keys are hundreds(i.e 100, 200, 300, 400, etc) and value is the number of prime numbers in each hundred. So for hundred `100` I have to find number of prime numbers in the range [100, 199].

I guess it is pretty clear that after second step there are only prime numbers left in the stream. However I don't know how to perform the third step and not sure about my implementation of the second.

Can you please help me to apply all the operations right?

Comment: Streams aren't terribly well suited for this. Not really the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a method `isPrime(int)` (you can easily find an implementation online), here's how you can group the results:

```
IntStream.range(2, n)
        .filter(i -> isPrime(i))
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i / 100 * 100,
                Collectors.summingInt(i -> 1)))
```

Comment: *if this number is not divisible by any other number that went through this filter already*, this answer is then not a solution for it. I understand that OP wasn't able to correctly specify its problem (at least ambiguous).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It just means a prime number. What's the problem?

Comment: If input is not range of integer from 2 to n, then he's spec doesn't define prime numbers.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Input? What input?

Comment: range of integers from 2 to n

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Sorry, I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: if input is 10, 20, 30, 40, then *number is not divisible by any other number that went through this filter* doesn't define "prime number".

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Again, there is no input, just a sequential stream of ints.

Answer (score 1):

I change your code a bit because if you check prev null in loop, it will get wrong IntStream.

You can run the code to check the result.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class StreamAPI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 1000;
        Supplier<IntStream> intStreamSupplier = () -> IntStream.range(2, n).filter(new IntPredicate() {

            ArrayList<Integer> prev = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            public boolean test(int value) {

                for ( int i = 0; i < prev.size(); i++ )
                {
                    if ( value % prev.get(i) == 0 )
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                prev.add(value);
                return true;
            }
        });

        Map<Integer, IntStream> map = new HashMap<>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i += 100 )
        {
            int j = i;
            IntStream subStream = intStreamSupplier.get().filter(new IntPredicate() {

                @Override public boolean test(int value) {

                    if ( j < value && value < ( j + 100 ) )
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            map.put(i, subStream);
        }

        for ( Map.Entry<Integer, IntStream> entry : map.entrySet() )
        {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            IntStream value = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println("key: " + key);
            int[] arr = value.toArray();
            for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
            {
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```